# using selenium to locate dates of reviews not replys, python

Tags: python, selenium

how would i get the date from reviews not replies?

current code is:

```
date_ref = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "time")
```

but that gets both date from reviews and replies

Reviews

```
<time datetime="2022-02-03T06:11:02.000Z" class="" data-service-review-date-time-ago="true" title="Thursday, 3 February 2022, 05:11:02 pm">3 Feb 2022</time>
```

Replies

```
<time datetime="2022-02-07T03:31:52.999Z" 
class="typography_typography__QgicV typography_bodysmall__irytL typography_color-gray-6__TogX2 typography_weight-regular__TWEnf typography_fontstyle-normal__kHyN3 styles_replyDate__Iem0_" data-service-review-business-reply-date-time-ago="true" title="Monday, 7 February 2022, 02:31:52 pm">7 Feb 2022</time>
```

how can i grab the date from the reviews but not the replies?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `TAG_NAME` which is the same for both reviews and replies. Therefore results in `2 nodes`, (could be many however that depends on your `HTML-DOM`).

If you want to differentiate the nodes, I see that `data-service-review-date-time-ago` attribute is unique for review.

Hence changing that to either CSS/XPATH would get the job done.

**CSS:** `time[data-service-review-date-time-ago]`

**XPATH:** `//time[@data-service-review-date-time-ago]`

You can call them using `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//time[@data-service-review-date-time-ago]")` or `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "time[data-service-review-date-time-ago]")` etc.

Also, note that you are using `find_elements` which would return a list of web elements, may be you wanted to use `find_element` if you were targeting the first node.